# Should I use lucene library to index my dataset for the first time?

Tags: http, solr, lucene

We are doing some poc with solr and one of the paths we are considering is to do the first time indexing of the dataset with lucene. Then make solr read this index and any subsequent smaller indexing with solr.
The rational being that solr,a web server will have to transport this dataset over http which could be a bottleneck. 
Dataset size is around 500GB. More than how to go about this, I am interested to know if we should be even trying to do it.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: you want to do a 500 GB index on 1 Solr server? also, it's weird why http transporting will be a bottleneck, but lucene will do good in that case?

Comment: Why not just run a local Solr instance for the initial index step? Writing a separate application using the lucene library to create the index, getting that into a solr instance, and making sure it's all consistent with your solr schema... that sounds like a lot more trouble than just waiting a bit longer for a one-time process to complete.

Comment: @Mysterion I plan to see the performance on 1 server and do more testing by splitting into shards. In solr documentation it says 2Billion documents can be indexed on 1 server. Hoping this would suffice. I understand lucene is a library which will index data onto the disk, so I would not be dealing with transferring the data over http. Hope this explanation is better.

Answer (score 0):

If you are doing POC on Solr, then you should do the indexing using Solr itself so that you find out more about Solr, it reduces your indexing task for which you have to write java code. If you want to improve the relevance then you could implement the custom plugins using lucene and then deploy it in Solr.

If you would do the indexing using the lucene it would be fast enough but with the large dataset there comes various things like high availability, performance, etc

So I would suggest you do the indexing using the Solr in standalone and Solrcloud mode then you could compare that which approach you would like to take.